# Replicating two directional table base graphics plot using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Base graphics can plot a sort of bidirectional histogram using factorial data. This can be useful in certain situations such as demonstrating unusual relationships between 2 variables.

An example of this can be shown below using the mtcars dataset

```
library(ggplot); library(dplyr)
table(as.factor(mtcars$cyl), as.factor(mtcars$carb)) %>% plot
```

[image: Base graphics representation]

How can I create a similar plot using ggplot? I have tried the following

```
mtcars %>% ggplot(., aes(x = as.factor(cyl), y = as.factor(carb))) +geom_density2d()
mtcars %>% ggplot(., aes(x = as.factor(cyl), y = as.factor(carb))) +geom_raster()
```

However the first only shows a blank canvas, and the second has data but they are not dimensioned proportionally. If the variables are not factorial it is not a problem but is they are the image doesn't work.

Comment: I think what you want is a treemap.  There are treemap packages that ride along ggplot, I believe.  See e.g. https://www.ggplot2-exts.org/ggraph.html